# Iterate all columns, mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a generic trigger that will be used for about 20 different tables in a mysql database. I know that there will be some table-specific in each trigger, but I would like to keep that to a minimum. 
Currently, I am trying to iterate through all columns, but it doesn't seem to be possible. Is it possible to iterate all columns and get the new value?

I am thinking, something like: NEW[column-name]..
Where "column-name" is the result from a select-query in information_schema table.

**Edit:**

Thanks!
I was asked to add more information about the tables. 
Each table is more or less unique. The only thing that *might* be the same is the column "id", which is a unique row-id. Auto-increment.
Thats why I want to dynamically iterate all columns in the trigger.I know that for 20 tables, there will be 20 triggers,  But I want to keep the number of unique parameters in each trigger as low as possible.

So for example

Table1: 
* id, user_id, value, timestamp
Table2: 
* id, class_id, user_name, value_1, value_2, value_3, time, date

And pseudo code:

```
For each row:
  For each 'column' in table_columns:
    something[column] =  NEW[column];
send(something);
```

send() is a user-defined function that I've created.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some more specific examples? What does your table look like? Can you post some sample data and expected results?

Comment: In SQL we don't iterate through columns, we **know** them in advance. The fact you must iterate through columns indicates some sort of a task you need to do and your attempted solution is column iteration. This just screams wrong. Easer way, at least for you, is to specify what you need or want to do, what you came up with and how you got stuck (obviously you got stuck at iterating through columns). Or, you can completely ignore what I wrote and go down the harder way.

Comment: The final output of this problem is to for some tables send, via socket (my UDF), and later via MQTT, the updates & inserts of some specific tables..  The format of data sent has to be JSON.